# Tensorflow LSTM model parameter learning inside parameter

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm tryinig to train my LSTM model in tensorflow and my module has to calculate parameter inside parameter. And i want to train both parameters altogether.
More details are in the picture below.

I think that tensorflow LSTM module's input must be a perfect sequence and parameters like "tf.placeholder".
How can i do this in tensorflow? Or can you recommend another appropriate framework better than tensorflow in this task?

Sorry for my poor english.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your usage of the word parameter is quite confusing. Normally parameters are referred as trainable parameters and therefore every variable which is trained by the optimizer. There are also so-called hyper-parameters, which have to be set per hand e.g. like the model topology.

Tensorflow work with tensors, which are representations of data which are used to build the workflow and are filled with data during run time via placeholder which is like an entry point for the data.

Also, if you have trouble to build your model in tensorflow, then there is also [keras](https://keras.io/). Keras can run with tensorflow as its backend but model building is much easier. Also, keras is also available in the tensorflow API as tf.keras. In keras one or multiple LSTMs are simplified as a layer which can be added to your model.

If you like a more specific answer to your question, please provide code to describe your problem.

Comment: As you commented, I want to update another parameter conditionally during run time. I specified my problem as possible as i can here, i hope you understand my poor description. thanks a lot. https://github.com/taebinalive/test

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want an if statement inside your graph. I doubt that this is possible because every operaton needs to be derivable. You could update the second parameter every time and give the update a weight close to 0/1 depending on your classification output.